# ORA-06550: line 1, column 65: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-5, procedures

My code

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc IS
       CurrDep Number;
       Tot Number;
       accm Number;

       Cursor Cur_lcd is
           select  * from Courier_Scanner;
       Cur_row Courier_Scanner%rowtype;
   Begin

       for Cur_row  in Cur_lcd
       Loop
           CurrDep := (Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE- Cur_row.SALVAGE)/Cur_row.LIFE_SPAN;
           accm:= Cur_row.TOTAL_ACC_DEP;
           Tot := CurrDep + accm;

           Update Courier_Scanner
           set CURR_PRED_DEP = Currdep,
               TOTAL_ACC_DEP = Tot,
               NET_VALUE = Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE-Tot 
               ACCUMULATED_DEP = accm
           where  SC_NO = Cur_row.SC_NO;
       end loop;

       commit;
   END myproc;
```

ERROR:

```
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 65: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"                                         
    when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto 
    if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an 
    identifier> <a double-
```

Can anyone help me out by pointing out the exact error in the procedure. I have spent hours, but couldn't see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a comma(`,`) missing in update statement at the line

> NET_VALUE= Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE-Tot     ACCUMULATED_DEP=accm where 
>   SC_NO =Cur_row.SC_NO;

Correct it as below:

```
UPDATE Courier_Scanner
         SET CURR_PRED_DEP = Currdep,
             TOTAL_ACC_DEP = Tot,
             NET_VALUE = Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE - Tot,
             ACCUMULATED_DEP = accm
       WHERE SC_NO = Cur_row.SC_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with that stored procedure. Just be sure to put a forward slash on a separate line after each PL/SQL block that you are compiling if you are using TOAD or SQL*Plus. Forward slash is the default block terminator in TOAD and SQL*Plus.